# How can I write custom methods for drawing in Java Canvas?

Tags: java, canvas

I wrote a library for customized draw Methods in JavaScript, which I want to rewrite for Java. In Javascript it looks like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function rect(x, y, sizex, sizey, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, sizex, sizey);
}

//more functions...
```

Now don't know how to draw with custom methods in Java without hardcoding everything into the `paint(Graphics g)` method.

I want to have a class "Graphic" which can be used by other classes to call my own `rect` method. Other classes should use it like this:

```
Graphic g = new Graphic(myFrame);
public void drawThing(x,y){
    g.rect(x,y,50,50,Color.RED);
    g.rect(x + 50,y,50,50,Color.BLUE);
}
```

My Java code looks like this but what should I write at the "???"

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Graphic extends Canvas {

    public Graphic(JFrame f) {
        setSize(new Dimension(f.getContentPane().getWidth(),f.getContentPane().getHeight()));
    }

    public void rect(int x, int y,
            int sizeX, int sizeY, Color c) {
        ???.setColor(c);
        ???.fillRect(x, y, sizeX, sizeY);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        ???
    }
}
```

I already looked on plenty of websites but everyone seems to draw everything already in the paint method.

Comment: Cast the graphics object to Graphics2d, and you will have plenty of methods to draw, including rectangles. For custom drawing create an object that implements Shape.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html